# How to Implement IDialogService to wrap Messsage.Box for testing purposes

Tags: c#

I need to so some unit testing with Nunit and found that my calls to MessageBox.Show were getting in the way. I was looking at IDialogService and trying to implement it.

Here is the interface.

```
 namespace Exec.Core.Interfaces
    {
      public interface IDialogService
      {

        DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons);

        DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption);

       DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text);
      }
    }
```

Here is the implementation.

```
namespace Exec.Core
{
  public interface IDialogService
  {
 }

    public  DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
      return MessageBox.Show( text,  caption, buttons,  icon);
    }

    public  DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    {
      return MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons);
    }
 }
}
```

and here it is comming into a class

```
namespace JobExec.Modules.Tasks
{
private  IDialogService dialogService;


     public partial class frmTask : form
     {
        private void Load_Form( object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           dialogService = new DialogService();

            other stuff
        }
    }

}
```

My understanding of the objective is that I am trying to wrap a class around Message.Box so that I can mock it out with NSubstitute

The only way I can get it to work is the line      `dialogService = new DialogService();`  in the load_form event.

It seems that I will need to add  `private  IDialogService dialogService;` into the top of every class and `dialogService = new DialogService();` into every constructor of every class.

This seems awfully smelly.

Is is my methodology correct?

Thanks,

Colin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more common to pass an instance of the interface into your form constructor.

The point being, you can't call `new DialogService()` in your form, as that takes away the chance to swap it out for the version that doesn't actually show a MessageBox.

Then, when it comes to unit testing, you can pass in the mock implementation of `IDialogService` which doesn't show a MessageBox.

This is dependency injection. Some people use DI frameworks but you don't need a framework for this. If you have a large object graph with lots of dependencies then using a framework makes things easier to manage, after some setting up.

There are alternative approaches, of course: you could say have some kind of static DialogServiceFactory that you could change at runtime, which you then reference from each module, or even something like a Service Locator.

Just to note you  will need to keep the default constructor for designer support, and call it from the injecting constructor.

Comment: Thanks for replying.    So my premise is  sort of correct.  The change is that every class that I am going to test, I need to pass the instance in through the constructor.  It would seem to me that this need to occur from the main program and on.  Colin

Comment: @stuartd- thanks for the clarifications.   I actually installed Ninject and got that working.  Its going to be a rather large application and it will need some some other interfaces so I might as well bite the bullet early.  The set up was interesting. Now to get Nsubstitute working with the interfaces. thanks for the help.    Colin